# Processing different matches in a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to construct a `RegExp` that matches either the first letter of the first word, or the first letter of non-first words, but I want to be able to distinguish between these two kinds matches so I can process non-first-word matches differently.

For example I want to always capitalise the first word and all other words apart from instances of "bam" that are not the first word.

How can I do this?

```
function titleCase(title) {
    return title.replace(/\b(.)/g, (str, p1) => {         
         return p1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

titleCase('foo bar bam'); // Foo Bar Bam - but I want Foo Bar bam
```

Comment: There's not really a *good* way to do that in JavaScript, but you can do something like making sure each alternative is in a group and then looking for the non-empty group in the match results. It would be super useful if the RegExp instance had some sort of indicator mechanism that would allow the post-match search to be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple regex pieces together like `/(option 1)|(option 2)/g`

Then your callback will receive either of:

```
callback(match, option1, undefined, offset, subject) // left side matched
callback(match, undefined, option2, offset, subject) // right side matched
```

Using this, your callback can look like:

```
(str, p1, p2) => {
    if( p1) ...
    else if( p2) ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of `titleCase` which will capitalize the first letter of every word-like element in the string.

```
function titleCase(title) {
  return title.replace(/\b(\w)(.*?)\b/g, (match, g1, g2) => `${g1.toUpperCase()}${g2}`)
}
```

1. In this example, `/\b(\w)(.*?)\b/g` will match a word boundary (`\b`) followed by a word character (`\w`). We capture the first letter using the grouping `(\w)`, and is used as `g1` in the replace function.
2. Then we capture the remaining portion of the word using the group `(.*?)`, which is referenced using `g2` in the replacer.
3. Finally, a template string is used to capitalize the first letter group and concatenate the result with the remaining match of the word.